# java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #2 bootstrap method on CameraX (1.0.0-alpha06)

Tags: android, crash, android-camerax

I am trying to use CameraX API to fetch photo, but after I updated to new API version 1.0.0-alpha06 it started to crash on

```
CameraX.bindToLifecycle(...)
```

method.

The log of error is:

```
Process: com.aximetria.aximetria.debug, PID: 2629
    java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #2 bootstrap method
        at androidx.camera.core.Preview.updateListener(Preview.java:368)
        at androidx.camera.core.Preview.updateOutput(Preview.java:586)
        at androidx.camera.core.Preview.updateConfigAndOutput(Preview.java:363)
        at androidx.camera.core.Preview.onSuggestedResolutionUpdated(Preview.java:524)
        at androidx.camera.core.UseCase.updateSuggestedResolution(UseCase.java:408)
        at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.calculateSuggestedResolutions(CameraX.java:684)
        at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.bindToLifecycle(CameraX.java:195)
        at com.aximetria.aximetria.ui.main.profile.avatar.TakeAvatarPhotoFragment.initCamera(TakeAvatarPhotoFragment.kt:169)
        at com.aximetria.aximetria.ui.main.profile.avatar.TakeAvatarPhotoFragment.initCamera$default(TakeAvatarPhotoFragment.kt:117)
        at com.aximetria.aximetria.ui.main.profile.avatar.TakeAvatarPhotoFragment$onViewCreated$1.onPermissionsChecked(TakeAvatarPhotoFragment.kt:55)
    ...
```

My code is:

```
    private fun initCamera(reverseFacing: Boolean = false) {
        ...

        val previewConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder()
                .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
                .setLensFacing(lensFacing)
                .build()

        val preview = Preview(previewConfig)
        preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener { previewOutput ->
            val parent = binding.preview.parent as ViewGroup
            parent.removeView(binding.preview)
            parent.addView(binding.preview, 0)
            binding.preview.surfaceTexture = previewOutput.surfaceTexture
        }

        val captureConfig = ImageCaptureConfig.Builder()
                .setFlashMode(flashMode)
                .setLensFacing(lensFacing)
                .build()

        val capture = ImageCapture(captureConfig)

        binding.takeAPhoto.setOnClickListener {
            ...
            val imageFile = createTempFile(System.currentTimeMillis().toString(), ".jpg")
            capture.takePicture(imageFile, this, object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener {
                override fun onImageSaved(file: File) {
                    ...
                }

                override fun onError(imageCaptureError: ImageCapture.ImageCaptureError, message: String, cause: Throwable?) {
                    ...
                }
            })
        }

        CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, capture, preview)
    }
```

Is anyone know what caused this crash? I cannot see any related information in documentation (which by this time is out of date for CameraX)

Comment: if the version is still in alpha, it might just be a bug with the library ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody seems right, I have the same bug with alpha06 version of the library, but going back to alpha05 fixes it.

Comment: I have the same problem.. so I roll back to the alpha05

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @a-local-nobody, @stéphane-péchard and @yoonhok rightly said the bug in alpha-6 version of library. Roll back to alpha-05 also removed crashes in my case.

Comment: I tried to rollback to alpha-05 but alpha-06 doesn't get deleted and still appears, maybe you have an idea why?

Comment: what do you mean by arrear?

Comment: I mean it is still alpha-06 in code, even though i changed the dependency in gradle

Comment: try to do project clean and file->invalidate caches/restart

Comment: besides check what both libraries is in version 5. I use:     
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:1.0.0-alpha05"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-alpha05"

Comment: Still same after invalidating caches/restart, it looks like alpha 06 is forced downloaded

Comment: You can check out the solution i posted below, it worked for me. Didn't need to downgrade versions

Comment: I had similar error which occurred after I added retrofit to the dependency while I was using Picasso.

Answer (score 49):

Add this in gradle.

> CameraX needs some methods that are part of Java 8, so we need to set our compile options accordingly. At the end of the android block, right after buildTypes, add the following:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Comment: For me works like this:
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }

Answer (score 21):

I have fixed this issue by adding Java8 to app build.gradle

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the following lines into build.gradle(:app) file :

```
android{

  compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }    
}
```

Comment: Also in here, are all your answers copy of previous answers?